# 'sliding' text effect in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a log that is multiline textbox that keeps updating using AppendText. I want to make an effect that when new data arrives it smoothly scrools in from the bottom instead of simply appearing. How can I do this flicker free? one idea I had is to make textbox height higher and then change the y coordinate of the textbox, but seems like an bad idea. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If you want the text to slide up from the bottom, simply prefix a bunch of white space (lines) and slowly delete the white space, making it appear to the user that the text was scrolling upward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after updating the textbox

```
    // Textbox update code

    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite I'm looking for. I need a way to make a similar effect like if you would scroll up or down with mouse scroll button, it goes smooth from one point to another. Seems like I would need some kind of loop and decrease y value on each new data arrival.